# how does Google's "Google search 2.0" app launches other apps on iOs?

Tags: objective-c, ios, search, launcher

I always read that only url-like services can be started from an app in iOs, but now i've seen that the new "Google Search 2.0" app has got a panel where you can tap an icon and open one of the other Google's apps.

If you have not installed that app on your iphone it redirect you to the app store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other Google apps have URL schemes registered that can open them. UIApplication’s `-canOpenURL:` method will return NO if the URL scheme provided does not match an installed application, so in that case they’re redirecting to the App Store link for the app in question.